# RSA: security of LSB in The Generic Model of Computation

Tags: rsa, factoring

In this [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/260.pdf) Maurer and Aggarwal showed that in generic model of computation breaking RSA is equivalent to factoring. It is also known that the LSB of an encrypted message is as hard as breaking RSA.(i.e If there is an algorithm that find the lsb of the message m from the ciphertext c, then we can recover m). So I was wondering, does it follow that the LSB of RSA is a hard as factoring in the generic model of computation?

Comment: Do you have a Reference for: "It is also known that the LSB of an encrypted message is as hard as breaking RSA."?

Comment: @kodlu, have a look at this post https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11053/rsa-least-significant-bit-oracle-attack