# How can I extend the RSA LSB Oracle attack, to n-LSBs?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, attack, decryption-oracle

Suppose we have an RSA-Oracle that can encrypt and decrypt our input. The the decryption output is equal to: $ (C^d \mod N) \mod 2^n $.
How can I extend the LSB oracle attack, using the using knowledge about the last n-bits of the plaintext?

Comment: If think the question assumes an RSA decryption oracle accepting $C$, giving $(C^d\bmod N)\bmod2^n$ for $n>1$; and the Q wants to optimize the number of queries to decipher one ciphertext compared to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11053/555). Critic: In RSA, encryption is with the public key, and availability of an encrypting oracle follows (and needs not be an assumption as in the Q).

Comment: Again: the attack with $n=1$ is discussed [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11053/555). Also, a never related question is [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/105976/555). But until it's clarified what the present question asks, I can't be quite sure one is a dupe of the other.